# Undefined variable: product_item in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to update selected items and this is my code:

controller:

```
public  function updatesyncFiles(Request $request , $id){
       $product_item = Singleproduct::find($id);
        $files = $request->input('files');
        if ($product_item && is_array($files)){
            $product_item->file()->sync($files);
        }
    }
```

blade:

```
@if( $files && count($files) > 0)
        <form action="{{ route('product.sync_files'  ,  $product_item ) }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field()  }}
            <h3 style="color: black; ">فایل مربوطه:</h3>
            <section class="panel">
                <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
            <ul>
                @foreach($files as $file)
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="{{ $file->file_id  }}" {{ isset($id) && in_array($file->id,$id) ? 'checked':''  }}>
                        {{ $file->file_name }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit_product_files" value="ذخیره اطلاعات">
            </div>
                </table>
            </section>
        </form>
    @endif
```

and the error is: "Undefined variable: product_item"
what is the problem??

Comment: plz post the action's code that render this view.

Comment: what is your route and controller method that renders the view?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your variables to the view like this:

```php
return view('your_view', [
    'product_item' => $product_item
]);
```

Also not that you should pass an array to 2nd argument of the `route` method:

```php
{{ route('product.sync_files', ['product_id' => $product_item]) }}
```